# How can we convert JSON to .csv file using python ? my json value has array of data and dictionary formation as :

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{
       "userName" : "Jhon",
        "status" : "success",
        "id" : 1234,
        "myData" : {
          "data1": [1,2,3,4],
             "data2": [1,2,3,4],
             "data3": [1,2,3,4],
             "data4": 25,
             "data5" : 12
             },
        "currentStatus" : true
}
```

How this data is converted to tabler form?

```
userName  Status  Id   data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 currentStatus
Jhon      success 1234  1     1     1     25     12   true
Jhon      success 1234  2     2     2     25     12   true
Jhon      success 1234  3     3     3     25     12   true
Jhon      success 1234  4     4     4     25     12   true
```

tabluar form should be above pattern. How can this done using python? can anyone help me out.

Comment: please provide the code of what you have tried?

Comment: Why not just use pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I'm new to handle this json to .csv conversion, I went to through many answers but I ended up with none.

Comment: What should happen if some of the `dataX` lists are different lengths?

Comment: @Barmar but my dataX has the same length. DataX lists don't have different lengths.

Comment: Is it always `data1` through `data5`, or can that be different sizes? Are the first 3 always lists and the last 2 numbers, or can that change?

Comment: As you can see, it's really hard to answer a question like this if you don't provide good specifications of how it should work. It's hard to extrapolate from a single example.

Comment: Basically, you just need to write a loop that iterates over all the `dataX` lists, and writes a row to the CSV for each element. To handle the non-lists, replace them with a list that duplicates the value the same number of times as one of the other `dataX` lengths.

Comment: So `"data4": 25` becomes `"data4": [25, 25, 25, 25]`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You can't have a comma at the end of an object. Do you really have `"data5" : 12,` or is that a copying error?

Comment: @Barmar data1 throught data5 can differ there size like it goes through data8 also .The lists size will always same in myData. first 3 always lists and the last 2 numbers, can change. data1 to data5 will list and 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the loop when writing to the CSV file, replace all the `dataX` items that are just numbers with a list of 4 copies of the number. That way you can index all of them the same way.

```
import json
import csv

json = '''
    {
           "userName" : "Jhon",
            "status" : "success",
            "id" : 1234,
            "myData" : {
                "data1": [1,2,3,4],
                "data2": [1,2,3,4],
                "data3": [1,2,3,4],
                "data4": 25,
                "data5" : 12
            },
            "currentStatus" : true
    }'''
data = json.loads(json)
for key, val in data['myData']:
    if type(val) is not list:
        data['myData'][key] = [val]*4 # convert scalar to list

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    csvfile = csv.writer(f)
    # write header row
    csvfile.writerow(['userName', 'Status', 'Id'] + data['myData'].keys() + ['currentStatus'])
    prefix = [data['userName'], data['status'], data['id']
    suffix = [data['currentStatus']]
    for i in range(4):
        row = prefix[:]
        for d in data['myData']:
            row.append(d[i])
        row += suffix
        csvfile.writerow(row)
```

There's probably a simpler way to transpose the dictionary of lists into a 2-dimensional list.

Comment: before writing into csv file can the json data can sort ?

Comment: Of course. You can do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: i'm trying with this code for sorting 
data= sorted(data.items(), key= operator.itemgetter(1))
before writing into the CSV file, But i was not able to do this

Comment: It should be `data['myData'] = sorted(data['myData'], key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

Comment: yeah myData is sorting, but  while you print data['myData'], Only keys are printing.
It should give sorted keys and values right ?

Comment: Use `data['myData'].values()` to get the values instead of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Not a python answer, and just for information, using [jq command line parser](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

```
jq -r '(["userName","status","id","data1",
          "data2","data3","data4","data5","currentStatus"],    # header string
        range(0;.myData.data1|length) as $i|                   # $i=table index 
        [.userName,.status,.id,.myData.data1[$i],
         .myData.data2[$i],.myData.data3[$i],
         .myData.data4,.myData.data5,.currentStatus]) |        # extract values
       @tsv                                                    # format as tab separated value
' file | column -t                                             # display in column
```

This assumes that the number of element of the `data1` array is same for all other arrays.